# git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git, github, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I connected with bitbucket and I installed Git and sourcetree in my computer and I try to connect sourcetree and bitbucket together. but I couldn't connect both. when I try to clone repository source path, it says

```
this is not a valid source path... 
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

[image]

like this error

I don't have any idea about credential-osxkeychain file, and I'm using windows os

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Is there any chance that

`$ git config --get credential.helper`

is showing `osxkeychain`? This only works in OS X.

Try to find the according `.gitconfig` file (probably in $HOME) and remove the credential helper line.

EDIT: Atlassian documented the [issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=390496445) as well.

Comment: they documented the issue and the resolution only for OS X though. If OP is seeing it on Windows, it doesn't sound like the same thing.

Comment: As I said: remove the `[credential] helper = osxkeychain` line in gitconfig.

Comment: @iltempo yes it shows osxkeychain. how i remove it?

Comment: @iltempo i removed that line. now it dosen't showing the "osxkeychain" error, but i can't login to bitbucket through sourcetree.

Answer (score 4):

On a windows machine `WinCred` can be used to store credentials. Set Git to use windows credentials manager by running

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Try `git fetch or pull` and it should prompt credentials again and store it in credential manager.

Credential manager can be found at Control panel (search would point at right direction). This would come in handy to delete credentials quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try switch your **Git Instance** to **Apple Git**. It's worked for me.