# Fatal Invalid Credentials

Tags: git, eclipse, selenium, github, bitbucket

I tried to import my code from bitbucket in eclipse. Even though I have given the correct credentials, it was thrown a below error like invalid credentials.

[image]

[image]

I was tried to log in via manual with the same credentials. It was working. Couldn't figure out the problem.

As a second way, I tried with terminal but I received the below error.

[image]

Comment: Same error message here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34034330/6505250

Comment: For the command-line Git: `credentials-osxkeychain` is something you can only use on macOS. https credential helpers are generally OS-specific; you must use a Windows credential helper here. This sort of thing is one of many reasons I prefer ssh authentication over https authentication. In any case it looks like you can type your token in at the `Password for ...` prompt here. Use `git config` to fix up the credential helper setting afterward.